# Multiple Hyper-V virtual adapters after Windows 10 2004 update

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-10-v2004

After updating to Windows 10 version 2004, I see three virtual Ethernet adapters in my host OS, all connected to the Default Switch; before the update there were only two, Default Switch and Hvicsls. Anyone else seeing this? What's the third one for?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your question while trying to figure out the root of this behavior. I asked a similar question and got a good answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1584964/1167302) that you can check.

I wish if I could add this reply as a comment but don't have enough reputation :)