# Unintended Hyper-V Virtual Switches Appear After Upgrade to Windows 10 2004

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, hyper-v, windows-10-v2004

This morning I upgraded my system to Windows 10 2004, the upgrade went smooth and was through Windows Update. I am using Hyper-V as my virtualization program for virtual machines and to provide extra layer of protection to the system through core isolation.

After the upgrade, I noticed that a new Virtual Switch was created with the name "vEthernet (Ethernet)" where "Ethernet" within the parentheses is the name of my primary network adapter. Also noticed this behavior has a specific pattern of creating new vSwitches correspond to the adapters you have, e.g. if you created a new Virtual Switch and restarted the system, a new additional switch will appear with the name "vEthernet (your-new-switch-name)".

Tried to remove Hyper-V and reinstall it but no luck.

I am aware of a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1583298/multiple-hyper-v-virtual-adapters-after-windows-10-2004-update) on SuperUser but has no answers on it.

Any clues for the root of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post resumes the results of the study done by one poster:
[Windows Sandbox on Win10 2004 now creates vEthernet interface for every physical NIC?](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d443bc7f-4cf4-4a8a-9ae3-4fd359c37849/windows-sandbox-on-win10-2004-now-creates-vethernet-interface-for-every-physical-nic?forum=win10itprovirt)

His conclusion is that these new virtual switches were related to the feature of
Windows Sandbox. Uninstalling the Sandbox in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*
and reboot removes these switches. If you wish to keep Windows Sandbox,
you will need to also keep the switches.

I reproduce below his account:

> I updated to Win10 2004 (Build 19041.208 as of this writing) and I've
> noticed that on my system with Hyper-V and Windows Sandbox installed,
> I now have an auto-created vEthernet interface for every physical
> Ethernet interface on my system.  Each one is named "vEthernet
> (Physical interface name)".  This is occurring despite that fact that
> only virtual switch I have on my host system is the Default Switch.
>
> When I run "Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS", I see multiple
> adapters named "Container NIC xxxxxx", each showing as attached to the
> Default Switch.
>
> All of these vEthernet interfaces have auto-assigned 172.x.x.x IP
> addresses.  They cannot be deleted in Network Connections (option is
> grayed out) and if I use Device Manager to uninstall the actual
> Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet adapter device associated with these
> interfaces, they reappear after rebooting.  This behavior persisted
> even after I completely uninstalled Hyper-V, but when I reinstalled it
> and instead uninstalled Windows Sandbox, the vEthernet interfaces all
> disappeared, except for the one associated with the Default Switch,
> which I expected to remain. And at that point, running
> "Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS" returned only one result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time writing a good reply with a well chosen quote! It is true that I have Windows Sandbox installed on my machine, and as I am not using it currently, I removed it, and I can confirm the result of the linked research, the newly added Virtual Adapters weren't there and preserving the "Default Switch". Again thank you for your time!